# Form Engine recommendations

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to find a form engine that can generate the markup from simpler instructions like `addTextField`. This is common in CMSs and frameworks, but I'm looking for something that I can use in a plain php non-CMS project. Does anyone know of a form engine like this? If you do and use it, please mention some of its features. If it has validation and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Zend_Framework` was the first that popped into my mind. The component you want is called `Zend_Form`. Although ZF is a full framework, and it is designed to be used in MVC (model view controller) applications, you can still Zend_Auth separately. However I will warn you there is a bit of a learning curve: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.html.

It supports lots of form elements, grouped forms, filtered inputs, validation (built-in validations and custom ones), input escaping, and element ordering.

Here's the Quick Start: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.quickstart.html to show you what you would be getting into if choose `Zend_Form`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference, I also found this

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jformphp/

though I haven't tested it yet, and maybe I will go with Zend as suggested by SimpleCoder

Answer (score 1):

The [form engine on Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jformphp/) is a lighter version of the Zend one. It supports classic functions as validation and filters.

The main difference with Zend is that JForm is more low level when it comes to layout. It is easier to define an fully custom form structure in HTML. Consequently, it takes more code to make a default form-table.